# htaccess remove index.php and add www to url in expressionengine

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, expressionengine

i made a website by expressionengine, in the htaccess i need to remove the index.php and also add www to none www url's.
here is my current .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Add www to url
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)/index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

</IfModule>
```

but the above code has some problems, it works when the url has the www itself and there is no index.php anywhere and everything is fine, but when i remove the www from the url to test the "add www" part it does not work any more and the url damages lik this:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?/segment1/segment2/
```

an index.php comes up. i don know what to do, any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
RewriteEngine On

#Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

it will remove `index.php` from the URL and add `www` as a prefix.

Comment: actually it works individually, the problem is when i want to remove index.php and add www

Comment: @Ajay - after trying many rule, finally this code worked for me.

Comment: Always here to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The www redirect probably doesn't work because there's no wildcard, keep it simple and specify your domain:

```
# Redirect to www
# -------------------
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I expect you have the removal and addition of index.php the wrong way around, I redirect it first if specified in the URL, then add it in hidden:

```
# Redirect specific index.php requests in URL
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also try with and without the ? on this line, depending on the server setup, this might not be needed:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```